# How close are the exponential maps on $\mathbb{S}^2$ at two nearby points?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the two dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and let $p, q \in \mathbb{S}^2$. Let $\text{exp}_{p}$ and $\text{exp}_{q}$ be the exponential maps on $\mathbb{S}^2$ at points $p$ and $q$ respectively. I am interested in the map $\psi := \text{exp}_{p}^{-1} \circ \text {exp}_{q}$ defined on the unit disc $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. I expect that if $p$ and $q$ are *nearby* points, then the map $\psi$ is close to the identity map. My question is: Is there a way to quantify this closeness? More precisely, is it possible to write the Taylor series expansion of $\psi = (\psi_1, \psi_2)$ around the origin as 
 \begin{align*}
 \psi_1(x,y) &= \psi_1(0) + \frac{\partial \psi_1}{\partial x}(0)~x + \frac{\partial \psi_1}{\partial y}(0)~ y + \ldots \\
 \psi_2(x,y) &= \psi_2(0) + \frac{\partial \psi_2}{\partial x}(0)~x + \frac{\partial \psi_2}{\partial y}(0)~ y + \ldots
 \end{align*}
 and show that the only significant coefficients in the above expansion are $\frac{\partial \psi_1}{\partial x}(0) \approx 1$, $\frac{\partial \psi_2}{\partial y}(0) \approx 1$ and all other partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^{m+n} \psi_i}{\partial^{m} x \partial^{n} y}(0) \approx 0$, for all other choices of $m,n$ and any $i = 1,2$.

Any relevant reference will also be helpful.

Thanks!